# A way to have local configuration overrides in Episerver that are not committed to git

Tags: asp.net, configuration, gitignore

I have an issue where developers keep accidentally committing local changes to `Web/connectionStrings.config` and `Web/web.config` etc. with values that only work on their machine.

And I don't blame them; in most systems I've used before there's a standard way to have local settings overrides that the server willt ry to import if the local file exists but uses the default settings if it does not exist so that this local override file can be added to .gitignore and never accidentally committed to the repo. (E.g. in django the convention is to have a settins/local.py that is imported by the main settings file)

But I haven't found any way to do this in episerver no matter what I search; but it seems bizarre to me that the system requires you to modify an important configuration file in order to use a local database instead of the common dev database; and then requires every developer to remember to manually add every file *except* the the config file in order not to cause lots of confusing errors for the others. Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: This question shouldn't be specific to Episerver, as the core solution is just a .NET solution. You may have more success if you approach it as a general .NET question.

Answer (score 1):

A way you can do it is to use `file` attribute on `<appsettings>` element in web.config:

**web.config**

You can add your file `Web.AppSettings.LocalDev.config` to `.gitignore` and in this file you can set value which will overwrite ones in web.config.

**Web.AppSettings.LocalDev.config**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="someKey" value="newValueValidForLocalDev" />
</appSettings>
```

To make sure it works only locally add transformation in your transformation file which you most probably have somewhere already, for example `Web.Release.config`:

```
<appSettings xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(file)">
</appSettings>
```

And BTW, @cjsharp1 is 100% right in his comment - this has nothing to do with `EpiServer`